# App crashes while navigating to start screen from Modal using Stack Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react native. So Everything working fine & smoothly until I add a feature to move user on start screen as soon he deletes his account. On delete first I confirm then call the delete api, in response I'm calling `navigation.navigate('Start Screen')`. But as soon my code reached to this function app crashes. I'm unable to find logs. On button click it just crashes first time, and other time it works fine. I've code in another modal where I'd same issue on first time but other time works fine. On other screens this function works fine.

react navigation version
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",

Here is my code in delete funcion

```
if (updatedAccounts.length === 0) {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    setNewPadlock();
    setTimeout(() => navigation.navigate('Start Screen'), 500);
}
```

So I found a way to use replace instead of navigate but it wasn't working on IOS, it works fine on Android.
I found an article that says, navigation.replace() doesn't work when modal is open. So I handled that this way

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(!deleteModalOpen && isDeleted){
    navigation.replace('Start Screen')
    setIsDeleted(false)
    }
  }, [deleteModalOpen]);
```

Now it works fine. but as soon I'm on home screen and clicks on button to move next screen app crashes.